# An exercise (about positive elements) in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra, $a\in A$ be a positive element and $b\in A$ be an arbitary element in $A$. Can we verify that  $$b^{*}ab\leq \|b\|^{2}a~~?$$

Comment: Is the algebra unital? What do you know about positive elements at this point?

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of $b^*ab\leq \|a\|b^*b$, which is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be missing something trivial- but this result seems to be false.

Let's take the $C^*$ algebra to be $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, $a=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$, $b=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $b^*b=I$, and $b^*ab=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, and it's not true that $b^*ab \leq ||b||^2a$